# Unknown Label - DELAY occurring in edsim51,8051 microprocessor

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, 8051, edsim51

i can't figure out the problem. it shows "Unknown Label - DELAY" in edsim51

```
Org 00h

Main:
    Mov A, #0FEh
    Mov P1, A
    Acall Delay
    
    Mov A, #0FFh
    Mov P1, A
    Acall Delay

    Djnz R1, Main  ; Repeat the code until R1 becomes zero

End
```

i can't figure out the problem

Comment: The problem is you don't have a `Delay`. Where is it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide the subroutine `Delay`, and so the assembler/linker cannot resolve the label to an address.

The solution is to provide the subroutine, as a separate source code module, or in the same source.

Answer (score 1):

The Delay subroutine is missing from your code.

```
Org 00h

Main:
    Mov A, #0FEh
    Mov P1, A
    Acall Delay
    
    Mov A, #0FFh
    Mov P1, A
    Acall Delay

    ;you forgot to give the R1 an initial value
    Djnz R1, Main  ; Repeat the code until R1 becomes zero

    ;If R1 equals zero halt the system
    JMP HALT
;For example this is a delay for 1 Microsecond while using FREQUENCY 11.0592MHZ
Delay:
    MOV R6,#2D  ;10uS delay
    DJNZ R6, $  ;'$' mean to jump on the same line
    RET

HALT:
    JMP $
End
```

Also don't forget to give an initial value for R1 that you are using in 'Djnz R1, Main'